# Python -- Count the number of distinct shapes filled with floodfill?

Tags: python, recursion, flood-fill

I'm trying to use a [floodfill function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) in a Python program to color a bunch of somewhat irregular green ovals and circles blue, and keep track of the number of distinct objects filled.

I've tried to do this using a recursive floodfill algorithm, but when I print out the count of objects filled, I get a number that's unrealistically large. It seems like every time the floodfill function is called (including being called within itself as part of the recursion), the count increases.

I haven't found a way to use floodfill without recursion.

Is there some way to implement a floodfill function without recursion (so the count will only update a single time when the function is called), or just simply count the number of holes filled by floodfill?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to already gives you a non-recursive solution.

Comment: show code, and what have you tried